# External USB drive fsck fails on boot

Tags: ext4, fstab, fsck, e2fsck

Yesterday I tried setting the fsck flag on fstab to 2 for the external USB HDD I use in my Raspberry Pi, so that it would be checked on boot, like:

```
proc                                       /proc           proc  defaults          0  0                                                                                 
/dev/mmcblk0p5                             /boot           vfat  defaults          0  2                                                                                 
/dev/mmcblk0p6                             /               ext4  defaults,noatime  0  1                                                                                 
UUID=909274d0-814e-4fe8-b254-4437ec8240c9  /media/pomf288  ext4  defaults,users    0  2
```

However, today the system failed to boot, reporting this:

`/dev/sda2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`

I understand that obviously the partition is mounted at boot time precisely because it's in the fstab, but so are the root and boot partitions, and both are checked without a problem.

Switching the '2' back to '0' solves the problem, but I would be interested in knowing what can be done about this.